# Smart type casting in python

Tags: python, types, casting, twisted

I am making api calls and receive a response back in json like so

```
result = {'foo': '123.456', 'bar': '23', 'donald': 'trump', 'time': '2016-04-07T05:31:49.532124Z'}
```

Although result is either a dictionary or a list, the contents are always strings. I want to cast these values to the appropriate type. (i.e. `'123.456'` to a float, `'23'` to an int, `'time'` to a datetime.)

My code works but it seems like there should be a simpler/more efficient way to do this. Is there?

Here's my version

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def is_int(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return a == b

def is_datetime(x):
    try:
        parse(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def smartcast(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return { k:smartcast(v) for k, v in x.items() }
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return map(smartcast, x)
    elif is_int(x):
        return int(x)
    elif is_float(x):
        return float(x)
    elif is_datetime(x):
        return parse(x)
    else:
        return x
```

Edit: If possible I'd like to avoid using `try` and `except`. I'd like to implement this into an asynchronous twisted program and I think `try` and `except` block so it just makes the program synchronous. I'm new to twisted so I'm not sure if that is true.

---

As per Francesco's solution, here's the updated code.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def smartcast(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return { k:smartcast(v) for k, v in x.items() }
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return map(smartcast, x)
    else:
        for t in [int, float, parse]:
            try:
                return t(x)
            except ValueError:
                continue
    return x
```

Comment: `and I think try and except block` - why do you think so? it doesn't block, exception handling has nothing to do with blocking.

Comment: I wasnt sure how it handled exceptions like that. I guess it doesnt block. I was confused because usually you use a `Deffered` with a `.errback` and I didnt know how different that was from an `except` or a `raise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what is the *appropriate type*? I am asking this to underline that sometimes also for humans it is not clear what the type is: are you sure that **"42"** is always an int or sometimes it has to be considered just as a string?

Anyway, as you did, you can build your solution with your rules that makes sense in your context.

In your case, you can simplify your code with a simple loop

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

tests = [int, float, parse]

def smartcast(value):
     for test in tests:
         try:
             return test(value)
         except ValueError:
             continue
     # No match
     return value
```

Comment: `lambda value: parse(value)` is the same as just `parse`

Comment: thank you, I improved the example with your comment!

Answer (score 0):

what about using ast.literal_eval()?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

voting up Francesco's answer.  You need an exception raised.