# How to check for a string's "natural" datatype in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a user inputting arguments to the command line when running a python3 script, and I wish to check whether specific arguments are floats, ints, booleans, or strings. I'm familiar with the errors that are thrown when a string like 'car' is cast to an int using the int() function, and am also familiar with using a try/except block to attempt to cast a string to an int, and if this is unsuccessful, how to map error messages to helpful output to the user. I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467619/smart-type-casting-in-python) previous question, which will probably do the job. Was just wondering if there had been any new development.

Not sure if this is possible, but looking for a smart type() function that could operate as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

smarttype(sys.argv[-1])
```

and is capable of handling the following kinds of inputs:

```
./script.py 50
./script.py True
./script.py 50.0
./script.py run
```

and output:

```
int
bool
float
str
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse “elementary” data types:

```
type(ast.literal_eval('50')) # outputs int
```

You need however a set of quotes to mark something as a string (otherwise every input could be taken as a string):

```
type(ast.literal_eval('run')) # error
type(ast.literal_eval('"run"')) # string
```

If you want to allow unqouted strings you could do the following:

```
def parse_data(x):
    """Takes a string x and returns the "value" of x"""
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        return x
```

Comment: @wonce Nice answer, but how would it handle str like `./script.py run` ?

Comment: hmm, why would it not automatically label run as a string?

Comment: I extended my answer to cover this